# ETSI Tx Power standard for short Range Devices. I am Confused

Tags: rf, wireless, transmitter

I came across the European Telecommunication Standards Institute (ETSI) standard for non specific Short Range Devices which is documented in [EN 300.200](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/300200_300299/30022001/02.04.01_40/en_30022001v020401o.pdf) .

On page 28 under Section 7.2.3 with Heading Limits, a table is mentioned which has regulations on max power of different frequency bands.

Owing to be under 1 GHz freqency range, all bands are long range bands. And some bands are allowed up to 500mW (+27dB) or 25mW (+14dB).

What I am confused that with this much transmission power how are these devices classified as Short Range Devices? Also with this high transmission power, what range can we expect from such SRDs?

Comment: This isn't really an EE question - it's semantics - what does short mean? How long is a piece of string? Does 500mW = 27dB or +27dBm?

Comment: The range depends a lot on the antenna what you have at the two sides. A simple dipole or a big parabola antenna makes a big difference in the range. What is short range is a question of definition. It is classified so.

Answer (score 1):

On a more serious note, the 500mW limit applies to two categories of transmitter namely smart meter reading and stolen goods tracking devices. Clearly the stolen goods tracking devices are going to be battery powered but so are gas meters and water meters. Electricity meters can derive local power of course.

When a device receives an interrogation transmission it has to wake up quickly and deliver a robust response that minimizes the likelihood of the interrogator receiving that response in error. Therefore, the ability to transmit a higher power level will reduce this risk. Remember this is the 169 MHz band and there is a fair bit of traffic in some countries (France uses ERMES for paging and I think Italy does). The spec is pan European so it has to cater for a broad range of different areas in different countries.

It boils down to this - sending a **single** strong RF response from a battery powered piece of equipment is more ecological than losing packets and retransmitting the message. [Here](http://www.ti.com/general/docs/lit/getliterature.tsp?literatureNumber=slyy042&fileType=pdf) is a document from TI that goes into some details. What is true for battery-powered smart meters is true of device tracking systems.